# What kind of data does TrelloScrum keep?

Tags: trello, google-chrome

[TrelloScrum](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jdbcdblgjdpmfninkoogcfpnkjmndgje/details) is a Chrome extension for doing Scrum in [Trello](http://trello.com/).
It 'has access to all your Trello data'.

Does it transmit anything to a server? If so, what information does this server retain?

Comment: https://github.com/Q42/TrelloScrum/issues/9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TrelloScrum stores nothing to any server! You can check it out in the code at [GitHub](https://github.com/Q42/TrelloScrum).

**Disclamer:** I'm a TrelloScrum co-author.

Comment: So how does the data get shared between multiple people?

Comment: @AdamSpiers - Assuming you mean scrum hours and the like, that's stored on Trello itself (for example, the days estimate is stored in the card title).